# How to flag landlord/tenant (aka legal) questions

Tags: discussion

Using [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/108547/53243) question as an example.

What is the best way to flag the question?  Nothing seems to fit.  It boils down to landlord / tenant relations and/or a legal question.

In any case, it can't be answered on this SE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Click *close* or *flag*.

[image]

## Close

- Click *off-topic because...*

[image]

- Select *Other*
- Type in a comment
- Click *Vote To Close*

[image]

## Flag

- Click *should be closed...*

[image]

- Follow instructions above for voting to close.

## Lower reputation users

If you're a lower reputation user, and you don't have the *other* option for closing questions. You can always simply flag the question for moderator attention.

- Click *flag*
- Select *in need of moderator attention*
- Type in a reason for flagging
- Click *Flag Question*

[image]